# Cannot upgrade gcc/g++ version?

Tags: linux, gcc, compiler-errors, g++, hpc

When I tried to install bedtools in ubuntu 18, it showed the error as below:

> ```
> cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++11"
>
> make[1]: * [../../../obj//FileRecordMgr.o] Error 1
> ```

I guess the problem comes from gcc/g++ version. Currently, gcc version is 4.4.7. However, I cannot upgrade gcc/g++ using `sudo` command because I am installing it on HPC cluster. Could you suggest me some alternative ways to solve this problem?

Comment: If you cannot install a C++11 compiler, the alternative is : Use a "bedtools2-bin package" compiled for *your* OS.

Answer (score 0):

> ... tried to install bedtools in ubuntu 18 ... unrecognized command
>   line option "-std=c++11". ... gcc version is 4.4.7

Ubuntu 18.04.2 : The default gcc / g++ is version 7.4.0 . Quite unusual that it is set to 4.4.7 . If you cannot change to g++-7.4, a "bedtools2-bin package" can be used.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/arq5x/bedtools2.git
$ cd bedtools2/
$ make   
        ### the folder bin/{bedtools + 38 scripts} is created
```

Package : bedtools2-bin_2.29.0-ubuntu18_amd64.tar.gz https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1OjAsgpzqx-sK_3PF8FUGuinYqW_jVEWg?usp=sharing

Unpack bedtools2-bin_2.29.0-ubuntu18_amd64.tar.gz :

```
$ cd bedtools2/
$ tar xvf bedtools2-bin_2.29.0-ubuntu18_amd64.tar.gz
```